# React Native Navigation drawer partially open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app that I had to upgrade to try and fix an Android issue. I'm now on .67.2. After doing nothing to change the code, my React Navigation Drawer is now stuck partially open on the screen. I don't see any relevant bugs, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Is there any resource to check why this is?

Picture (for context)[image]

Comment: It recently happens to me, the partial solution is to change `drawerType` to  `back` but it should conflict with the original UI.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: This happens when you open the app and the drawer automatically opens and sticks there so the user can't close? - this is what I experienced?

Comment: On app start it's like this. You can't even close it with the close button. It's just stuck there.

Comment: Do you use Expo Developer  Client?

Comment: No. react-native-cli

Comment: <Drawer.Navigator
     
        useLegacyImplementation
       
        screenOptions={{
          drawerType: "back",
          
        }}
       
      >

Comment: Try to change drawer type to back

Comment: I wish I would've known this sooner. I'm in the middle of reverting it back to a previous commit. If that doesn't work I'll give this a shot and give an update. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know progress

Comment: That did it! Thanks again. If you post it as an answer, I'll vote it for you. ;)

Comment: Yes, I did ,  approve for future readers reference

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when building the application as an apk but not on Expo Go. I solved the problem by downgrading the version of `react-native-reanimated` under version 3 (2.14.4) and also the version of `expo sdk` to version 48 because from 49, versions of `react-native-reanimated` lower than 3 are no longer supported.
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change drawer type  to `back`  instead to be `front`

```js
<Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation screenOptions={{ drawerType: "back", }} >
```